# Where/when/how/why did flags become part of Simchas Torah celebrations?

Tags: minhag, history, children-parenting, simchat-torah, provenance

Kids today all know that they have flags when dancing on Simchas Torah.

How, when, where, and/or why did the flags originate? (Someone decided it was fun, and then it caught on?) What pictures were on the original flags?

Comment: about the same time as good first aiders for eyes became available.

Answer (score 5):

From [Nitei Gavriel Succos 94:11:14](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?sits=1&req=46442&st=%u05D3%u05D2%u05DC) it seems to be a more recent Minhag.

> כתר שם טוב ח״ז עמוד רי׳׳ט, שנעשה להרבות שמחה ביניהם. וכ״ב בקובץ כרם
>   שלמה גליון תשרי תשמ״ג עמוד ה׳ מהגה״ק רבי משה מראזוודוב זצ״ל, עפ׳׳י סוד
>   טעם למנהגן של ישראל לעשות דגלים שנודע דג׳ רגלים פסח שבועות וסוכות,
>   אינון חסד גבורה תפארת ג׳ דגלי המרכבה, וחג הזה הוא דגל רביעי שבמרכבה,
>   ובהיות שזכרנו רזא דארבע דגלים דאינון סוד ד׳ רגלי המרכבה, לכן המנהג
>   בדגלים ע״כ. וכ״כ בספר מטעמים לסוכות אות קמ׳׳ב טעם שהנערים נושאין דגלים
>   בשמח׳׳ת, דכמו בתכסיסי מלחמה נושאין דגלים לסימן המלחמה כל מחנה ומחנה
>   נושא דגל שלו, כמו כן אנו מראין בזה שהרגלים שלנו ותכסיסי מלחמה שלנו הוא
>   התורה, וכ״כ מאור החיים שכ״ק אדמו״ר מוויזניץ זצ״ל אמר שמנהג ישראל
>   שילדים נושאין דגלים ואל יזלזל בו.‏

[Wikipedia](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%93%D7%92%D7%9C_%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%97%D7%AA_%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94) says it started in the 1700s, and the first flag said on it כי מציון תצא תורה ודבר ה' מירושלים - no source!

> דגל שמחת תורה המודפס הראשון בעולם, הודפס ככל הנראה במרכז אירופה, (יש
>   הסוברים שבווינה, אוסטריה)[דרוש מקור], על הדגל נכתב הפסוק: "כי מציון
>   תצא תורה ודבר ה' מירושלים".‏